# How can I make a cell and its elements look greyed out?

Tags: swift, uitableview, addsubview

I have a `UITableView` that is a list of articles. When the user taps an article, there’s a segue to it, then when they come back to the list I want that article to be marked ‘read’. Marked read, in this case, means that the cell should look greyed out. I’m trying to do this by creating a `UIView` and use it as an overlay on that cell.

Here's my latest attempt:

```
class PublicationTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var publicationTitle: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var authorName: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var authorInitials: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var authorImage: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var bottomBorder: UIView! 

  var pub: PublicationModel? 

  func updateCellProperties(publication: PublicationModel, indexPathRow: Int) { 
    pub = publication if let isRead = publication.isRead {

    // this is the overlay that I can’t get to work
    let readOverlayView = UIView()
    readOverlayView.tintColor = UIColor.grey3
    readOverlayView.alpha = 0.5
    self.addSubview(readOverlayView)

    // I was greying out just the title like this. This will go away if I get the overlay to work
    publicationTitle.textColor = isRead ? UIColor.grey3 : UIColor.grey1

  }
}

 // some helper methods…

}
```

I’ve stepped through the code and confirmed that for articles that have been read, the isRead flag is `true` and the code to create the readOverlayView is being executed.

I want all UI elements on the items to be greyed out which is why I'm not trying to change the cell's background color.

- Why does my readOverlayView have no effect on the appearance of the cell
- Is there a better way to achieve the effect I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

`readOverlayView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]` before adding it as a subview, to make it expand on all the cell.

I would suggest, however, to make this overlay view in the `Storyboard` file inside the cell, expose it here as `IBOutlet` ant simply set `isHidden` value in `updateCellProperties` method.

Good luck!

Comment: Excellent! Adding the view via the Storyboard and an @IBOutlet worked! Thanks!